# How is the font size measure in PBIX?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

We are developing a new report in PBIX using the template created by the UI experts. In their tool they mention the size of all of the elements in px: text box, buttons, font size, etc. However, when we try to fit the labels it does not work. So, how are these elements measure in PBIX, is there any oficial documentation for this. The client is very specific and we need to provide all the possible evidence for the changes that probably we will request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measured in points. From here https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-june-2019-feature-summary/#fontSizes

Consistent font sizes across visuals

> If you’ve been building Power BI reports for a while, you may have
> noticed that when you set the font size to a specific size, such as
> “8”, the size might look different, depending on where you’ve been
> setting it. The reason for this is that different places were either
> using pixels or points to represent the font size, and 8 pixels is a
> different size compared to 8 points. With this month, we’ve updated
> all the formatting options within our visuals to always use points.
> There are still a few places using pixels, such as the textbox, and we
> will work to update those places as well in the coming months.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!! That is the document we were looking at!

Comment: Sorry for asking again but, do you know if that has been implemented for the other objects :  text box, buttons, cards ? I do not know why but I do not find any further information about that after this article.

Comment: I think the article says all fonts have been standardised so I would assume so. Only testing can give you certainty though and there may be bugs you could raise with Microsoft.